# Identity Google App Engine Environtment Type

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

I just setup my first Go GAE (Google App Engine) last 2 months ago, and I forgot what environment type I've chosen (Whether Flexible or Standard edition).

Anybody here know how to identity what type of my Go GAE is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is via Cloud Console. Go to "App Engine" on the left side and then click on "Versions". For which version there's a column identifying "Standard" or "Flexible".